# Is my node's sync speed normal?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I'm running geth in a docker container. Params are

> --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.api eth,net,web3 --graphql --metrics

Node has been up an running for about 4 days. Upon checking sync status, I see the following log.

does it ever get to < 10 ?

> / # geth attach
>
> Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!
>
> instance: Geth/v1.10.5-stable-33ca98ec/linux-amd64/go1.16.6
>
> at block: 0 (Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC))
>
> datadir: /root/.ethereum
>
> modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0
> personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
>
> To exit, press ctrl-d
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 71
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 74
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 113
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 123
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 74
>
> > eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
>
> 86

Output of eth.syncing

> eth.syncing
> {   currentBlock: 12853680,   highestBlock: 12853761,   knownStates:
> 221603652,   pulledStates: 221603652,   startingBlock: 12849379 }

Comment: if you are syncing the state then this is normal, until state is downloaded in total you are going to see highest block increasing and current block increasing

Comment: Can you run just `eth.syncing` and post the result?

Comment: @bru53001 > eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 12853680,
  highestBlock: 12853761,
  knownStates: 221603652,
  pulledStates: 221603652,
  startingBlock: 12849379
}

Comment: You are far, far away from being in sync. You seem to have imported 220 million states until now, but the entire network has about 1.25 billion right now. Unfortunately, with how the network grew in the past months, fast sync isn't so fast anymore. Try using snap sync if you aren't already, it promises some speed improvements.

Comment: @bru53001 On geth help it says syncmode is defaulted to "snap". Then apparently it is not working. I am explicitly enabling it now

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with the storage in my node. I pointed storage to a new directory and now "snapshot" appears to be working fine, it has synced over 80% in last 48 hrs.

Geth outputs status at this point :

> INFO [07-22|12:50:15.193] State sync in progress
> synced=81.94% state=101.06GiB accounts=129,924,534@26.62GiB
> slots=361,649,239@72.61GiB codes=355,090@1.83GiB    eta=8h19m17.171s